# Create Pre-Populated Database Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an online learning website with modules students can enroll in. Each module contains a set of 5 classes.

To do this I intend to:

1. On enrollment, an empty one-to-many 'learning module' instance is created and attached to the student (a student can have many modules, but a module instance can only have one student).
2. Superusers can assign modules to students (preferably in Django's Admin and by going to Student). On doing this, the module's classes are copied into the students 'learning module' db instance at the click of a button.
3. Students can view their modules. If the student has multiple modules, modules will be separated with a space

My question is how can I create these modules class lists and store them, ready to be copied into a students 'learning module' database instance? Basically I need to store pre-filled database fields which can be copied to a database instance at the click of a button.

I know of [data fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures), but this seems more for initially populating a database and is done with shell.

My next problem will be finding out how to allow superusers to assign these modules to Students within Django Admin.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very broad. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Hi. I think I was approaching this problem wrong. Instead of copying this data into a table generated for each User, I ended up making a table containing Units, and another containing PackagesOfUnits. I then used data-fixtures to prefill the Units table. And created relationships many-to-many between Users and PackagesOfUnits.